# GeoServer TMS with leaflet coordinates are different

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, coordinates, tile-map-service

I use the example tiger-ny layer from geoserver with leaflet like this:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([62.92578, 32.08523], 13); 
L.tileLayer('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/tiger-ny/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  tms: true,
  crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
  attribution: false
}).addTo(map);
```

I can see the Map and all works but not with the correct latlng.
The coordinates latlng are completely different.
This map shows basically the central park in new york and the correct latlng should be (40.78546, -73.96583) but in this geoserver tms the central park is at (62.92578, 32.08523).

Leaflet with geoserver tms should show the location with the correct latlng, like the central park at (40.78546, -73.96583) and not at (62.92578, 32.08523).

I don't understand why the coordinates are wrong when i use the tms of the GeoServer?

Comment: Maybe not the (only) issue, but I think your CRS option must be set on the map object, rather than on your Tile Layer.

Comment: i set the crs option on the map object and now leaflet gives me this: getCenter:LatLng(81.49881, 32.03201). But it should be something like this: (40.78546, -73.96583). I don't understand whats going on with these strange coordinates?

Comment: Can you detail what object you do `getCenter` on?

Comment: i use getCenter() on my map object and get something like this: {lat: 81.52705192565918, lng: 32.05141067504883, equals: function, toString: function, distanceTo: function, …}

Comment: Do those coordinates make sense in respect with the map bounds? Latitude 81.5 degrees should get you close to the Northern limit for example. If so, there is probably an issue in your geoserver or in your cache (e.g. browser cache). Further troubleshooting would require more details from your situation, or better, online access to a map and server showing your problem.

Comment: I cannot share my geoserver. it runs on my local computer for testing. The Problem is, that i need the geoserver tms service with leaflet for a smartphone web app. because of this strange coordinates from my geoserver tms, i cannot use the check location function of my phone. Screenshot of my Layer Settings in Geoserver: http://i.imgur.com/Y2f8ZPt.png?1

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but here's the solution anyway:

GeoServer's tilematrix has Y-up as per GIS convention.  The Mapbox style of tilematrix has Y-down as per computer graphics convention.  The basic TMS protocol assumes Y-down, so Leaflet needs to know to reverse the Y coordinates of the tile matrix (remember this is the Y of the tilematrix and not the actual real world coordinates).

There is a way of [calculating](https://gist.github.com/tmcw/4954720) the reversed y value mathematically but in Leaflet 0.7 there is a `tms: true` option and in v 1.0 you can simply use `{-y}` for servers like GeoServer that follow the GIS convention.  See [here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html) and scroll to the bottom for more detail.